# PhpStorm uses Ctrl instead of Command

Tags: phpstorm, config

PhpStorm uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of 'Command' on Mac OS. Can anyone help me change it quickly? It's ruining my life

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html That guide should help you get your keyboard shortcuts set to command instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, it turns out I changed the keymap configuration to a different version and forgot about it.

I just switched to Default and now all cmd shortcuts work just fine.

To do this:

- Go to Preferences
- Click Keymap
- In the right screen, change the dropdown to your liking.